# How to distribute components inside slots on child list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a component which receives a list of items. Each one of those items will be a child component inside the main one. Each child component has a slot where I need to distribute content.

How do I distribute the content (the name) of each item to the correct slot?

The root app:

```
<div id="app">
  <test-list :items="items"></test-list>
</div>

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: [
        {id: 1, name: "item 1"},
        {id: 2, name: "item 2"},
        {id: 3, name: "item 3"},
        {id: 4, name: "item 4"},
        {id: 5, name: "item 5"},
    ]
  }
});
```

Main component:

```
Vue.component('test-list', {
  template: '#test-list',
  props: {
    items: []
  },
});

<script id='test-list' type='x-template'>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <test-item v-for="item in items" :id="item.id" :name="item.name"></test-item>
  </ul>
</script>
```

Child component:

```
Vue.component('test-item', {
  template: '#test-item',
  props: {
    id: 0,
    name: ""
  }
});

<script id='test-item' type='x-template'>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <slot>default text {{name}}</slot>
  </li>
</script>
```

The best I was able to do was to distribute the same content over all the items: [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/gmsa/sguky85t/)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm getting it right, [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/yerkopalma/sguky85t/3/) is what you want. You have to use [named slots](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Named-Slots), in this way:

root app

```
<test-list :items="items">    
</test-list>
```

Main component

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <test-item v-for="item in items" :id="item.id" :name="item.name">
        <span :slot="item.name"></span>
    </test-item>
  </ul>
```

Child component

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <slot :name="name">default text {{name}}</slot>
  </li>
```

Things to note:

1. The `slot` component is included in the child, with a name attribute
2. The element that is going in the slot is placed in the parent with a `slot` attribute.
3. Both attribute have a `v-on` directive (I used the `:` shorthand), so you can bind the content of your Vue instance

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Yerko, but your example doesn't work. It should display the <span> tag, not the default text. I also need to distribute the content from the root app, not from the v-for of the Main component.